# Why does my PDO query doesn't execute with fetch()?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, pdo, fetch-api

I'm trying to do an update statement through a button onclick event, but I'm not having success on running it with the fetch api.

I have this JavaScript function:

```
const changeProductAvailability = (id,status) => {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('product', id);
  formData.append('able', status);
  fetch("change-availability.php", {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
  })
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((text) => {
    console.log(text);
  })
}
```

and I have this in the change-availability.php:

```
  $query_sql = "UPDATE product SET able_to_order = :able WHERE id = :id";
  $data = [
    "able" => $_POST['able'],
    "id" => $_POST['product']
  ];
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($query_sql);
  $stmt->execute($data);

  if (!$stmt) {
    echo "Error on updating"
  }else{
    echo "Sucessfully changed";
  }
```

On the html I have a button that calls the function like this with the 2 parameters:

```
<button
  class="btn <?=$row["able_to_order"] == 0 ? "btn-success" : "btn-danger" ?>"
  onclick="changeProductAvailability(<?= $row['id'] .",".$row['able_to_order']?>)">
  <?=$row["able_to_order"] == 1 ? "Disable" : "Enable" ?>
</button>
```

The PDO statement works, as I've tried to directly open the page and changed to GET values on the data array. On button click I get the "Successfully changed" on the console, however, the values on the database don't change. What part of it am I doing wrong?

Comment: `!$stmt` doesn't do what you think it does. The return value of the call to `$stmt->execute()` returns the boolean value you should be testing against.

Comment: PDO will only return false if the query failed. If you want to see if any records were affected, you can check [the rowCount for affected rows](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php).

Comment: Ok, I've figured it out with your help. After changing the returning message to $stmt->rowCount() it returned "0 rows changed" which made me realise that it was actually my query that wasn't correct. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @esqew mentioned, !$stmt doesn't do what I was expecting, and instead I needed @aynber solution, to check if any rows were changed.

I found that the mistake was in the values passed to the query instead as I was passing the values that were already present in the database which returned a '0 rows changed'.